# performance hit with PDO in comparison with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just have migrated my code from `mysql_*` To `PDO` and amused to see the huge performance hit. I have been into reading of http://wooptoo.com/blog/pdo-vs-mysqli-performance-comparison/ and thought `PDO` will be more efficient.

But i think i may be doing something wrong which making my code much slower than expected.

i have created a `singleton` class

```
class db
      {

      static $dbinstance=null;  

      public static function getinstance()
      {

      if (!self::$dbinstance) 
         {
          try
            {
            self::$dbinstance=new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=inventory",'user','pass');
            self::$dbinstance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            }
          catch( PDOException $e)
           {
            die( '<b>Errors:</b> '.$e->getMessage());
           }
       }
          return self::$dbinstance;
     }
```

Below Code I'm Using to Insert (I Have cut the code short for simplicity)

```
    if(isset($_POST['Build']))
{
    $InCart=db::getinstance()->prepare("SELECT `Vendor`, `ItemType`, `ItemCode`, `ItemDesc`, `SerialNo`, `Asset_Code`, `ItmUnit`, `Qty`,`SiteId`, `id`, `Ownership`, `wh`,  `Phase`, `Category`, `Issue_Vendor`, `AssetName`, `po`, `FaultInfo`, `willreturn`, `Person`, `remarks`, `grnno`,stockid FROM temptable WHERE id=?");

    $insertinSIR=db::getinstance()->prepare("INSERT INTO Sir(SirNo,SiteId,Vendor,Type,ItemDesc,ItemCode,SerialNo,Unit,AssetCode,Qty,Region,Phase,Category,Issue_vendor,AssetName,ownership,Dated,PersonName,Remarks,po,invuser,grnno,WarehouseType,WarehouseLocation) values( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

  foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id)
      {
     $InCart->execute(array($id)); 
     $arr=$InCart->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        $insertinSIR->execute(array($a,$arr[8],$arr[0],$arr[1],$arr[3],$arr[2],$arr[4],$arr[6],$arr[5],$arr[7],$user,$arr[12],$arr[13],$vendor,$arr[15],$arr[10],$person,$remarks,$arr[16],$invuser,$arr[21],$whtype,$whlocation));

      }
```

I would Appreciate if someone point out the performance hitter?
**EDIT**

Is it the right way i'm preparing statements and executing in loop?

Comment: Define please "performance hit" and "much slower" in certain numbers and queries. What particular query runs "much slower" and how long it takes?

Comment: i have migrate my whole code to PDO and it taking aroung 6X more time in completing the whole script with the same checks i was doing with mysql_*

Answer (score 1):

Proposal:

```
INSERT INTO Sir (SirNo, ...)
     SELECT Vendor, ...
       FROM temptable
      WHERE id IN (?, ?, ...)
```

There's no need to pipe all the data through PHP to begin with. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html.

Comment: In My Case It won't help as after selecting from temptable i have to perform some checks and then depending on those checks will update or insert